# Python Tkinter: Window1 layout is changing when TopLevel runs

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am creating a simple software for our dental business. I am trying to view patient all the patient from another window but every time I click the `View Patient` button, the layout of the `Window1` is changing. What would be the possible problem of this.

This is my full code:

````
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkcalendar import DateEntry


class Window1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master1 = master
        self.master1.geometry('1190x750+0+0')
        self.master1.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master1.title('Wonder Smile Management System')

        self.topframe = Frame(self.master1, width=1060, height=70, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, pady=5, bd=3)
        self.topframe.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=(0, 10), ipadx=23)

        self.infoframe = Frame(self.master1, width=420, height=610, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, bd=3)
        self.infoframe.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=NW, padx=(5, 0), ipadx=3, ipady=4)

        self.rightframe = Frame(self.master1, width=367, height=680, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, bd=3)
        self.rightframe.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(4, 5))

        self.bottominfoframe = Frame(self.master1, width=420, height=200, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, pady=5, bd=3)
        self.bottominfoframe.grid(row=2, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky=NW, padx=(5, 0), pady=(15, 0), ipadx=115)

        self.bottomrightframe = Frame(self.master1, width=420, height=40, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, pady=10, bd=3)
        self.bottomrightframe.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky=NW, padx=(8, 5), ipady=4, ipadx=21)

        self.bottomframe =Frame(self.master1, width=420, height=610, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, pady=5, bd=4)
        self.bottomframe.grid(row=3, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky=NW, padx=(7, 5), pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=10)

        self.entryframe = Frame(self.master1, width=100, height=80, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, pady=5, bd=3)
        self.entryframe.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=NE, padx=(452, 12), pady=(5, 0), ipadx=16)

        self.lowestframe = Frame(self.master1, width=420, height=40, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, pady=5, bd=3)
        self.lowestframe.grid(row=4, column= 1, sticky=NE, padx=(10, 12), ipadx=7, ipady=3)


        self.Fullname = StringVar()
        self.Address = StringVar()
        self.Birthday = StringVar()
        self.MobileNumber = StringVar()

        #===== TOP FRAME ======
        self.titlename = Label(self.topframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), fg='orange', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='WONDER SMILE',
                             padx=485, pady=5)
        self.titlename.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #===== INFO FRAME =====
        self.rgstrlbl = Label(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), fg='orange',bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='REGISTRATION')
        self.rgstrlbl.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        self.lblname = Label(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange', text='Name:',
                             padx=2)
        self.lblname.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entryname = Entry(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.Fullname, bd=3,
                               insertwidth=5, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.entryname.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.lblage = Label(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange', text='Age:', padx=2)
        self.lblage.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entryage = Spinbox(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=3,
                              insertwidth=5, bg='white', width=18, justify='left', from_=1, to=100)
        self.entryage.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lbladdress = Label(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange',
                               text='Address:', padx=2)
        self.lbladdress.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entryaddress= Entry(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.Address, bd=3,
                                 insertwidth=5, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.entryaddress.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.lblbday = Label(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange',
                                 text='Birthday:', padx=2)
        self.lblbday.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entrybday= DateEntry(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=3,
                                     bg='white', justify='left', width=19, state='readonly')
        self.entrybday.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.lblmobnum = Label(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange',
                             text='Mobile Number:', padx=2)
        self.lblmobnum.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entrymobnum= Entry(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.MobileNumber, bd=3,
                                 insertwidth=5, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.entrymobnum.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.btnsubmit = Button(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='dark green', fg='orange',
                             text='Submit', bd=3, padx=3, width=12, cursor='hand2')
        self.btnsubmit.grid(row=6, column=1, ipadx=64, pady=5)

        self.pviewbtn = Button(self.infoframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='orange', fg='DeepSkyBlue4',
                              text='View Patient', bd=3, padx=3, width=20, cursor='hand2', command=self.view_patient)
        self.pviewbtn.grid(row=7, column=1, ipadx=28, pady=(5, 0))

        # ====== BOTTOM RIGHT FRAME ========
        self.selectedcombobox = StringVar(value='Choose Patient:')
        self.cmb = ttk.Combobox(self.bottomrightframe, font=('arial', 16, 'normal'),
                                   textvariable=self.selectedcombobox,
                                   width=15, state='readonly')
        self.cmb['values'] = ('Joseph', 'Carl', 'John')
        self.cmb.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(25, 0))

        self.selectedreport = StringVar(value='Choose Report:')
        self.comboreport= ttk.Combobox(self.bottomrightframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.selectedreport,
                                    width=35, state='readonly')
        self.comboreport.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(5,20))

        # =====Button=======
        self.btnedit = Button(self.bottomrightframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='orange', fg='DeepSkyBlue4',
                              text='Edit', bd=3, padx=3, width=20, cursor='hand2')
        self.btnedit.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(15, 0), padx=(25, 0))

        self.btnadd = Button(self.bottomrightframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='dark green', fg='orange',
                              text='Add', bd=3, padx=3, width=20, cursor='hand2')
        self.btnadd.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=(15, 0), padx=(45, 25))

        self.btndelete = Button(self.bottomrightframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='firebrick4', fg='orange',
                                text='Delete', bd=3, width=20, cursor='hand2')
        self.btndelete.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=(15, 0), padx=(5, 0))
        

        # ===== BOTTOM INFO FRAME ======
        self.adminlbl = Label(self.bottominfoframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), fg='orange', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='ADMINISTRATOR')
        self.adminlbl.pack(padx=5)

        self.incomelbl = Label(self.bottominfoframe, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='Income:')
        self.incomelbl.pack(padx=5)

        self.incomeamntlbl = Label(self.bottominfoframe, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), fg='orange', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='20513.38')
        self.incomeamntlbl.pack(padx=5)

        self.expenselbl = Label(self.bottominfoframe, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='Expenses:')
        self.expenselbl.pack(padx=5)

        self.expenseamntlbl = Label(self.bottominfoframe, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), fg='orange', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='1325.83')
        self.expenseamntlbl.pack(padx=5)

        

        self.logoutbtn = Button(self.bottominfoframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='firebrick4', fg='orange',
                              text='Logout', bd=3, padx=3, width=20, cursor='hand2')
        self.logoutbtn.pack()

        # ======= List ========
        self.report = [('John', '20', '09124631644', 'Adjusting braces')]

        self.patientlist = [('John', 20, 'Dasma', '12/25/00', '09512451255')]

        # ====== RIGHT FRAME =======
        # ====== Scrollbar =========
        self.t_scroll = Scrollbar(self.rightframe)
        self.t_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # ======= Treeview table ========
        self.t_table = ttk.Treeview(self.rightframe, yscrollcommand=self.t_scroll.set)
        self.tree_view_style = ttk.Style()
        self.tree_view_style.theme_use('default')
        self.tree_view_style.configure("Treeview", background='DeepSkyBlue4', foreground='orange', fieldbackground='DeepSkyBlue4')
        self.tree_view_style.map("Treeview", background=[('selected', 'orange')], foreground=[('selected', 'black')])
        self.tree_view_style.configure("Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Arial', 10))

        self.t_scroll.config(command=self.t_table.yview)

        self.t_table['column'] = ('Name', 'Age', 'Mobile Number', 'Report')

        self.t_table.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
        self.t_table.column('Name', width=100, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table.column('Age', width=100, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table.column('Mobile Number', width=100, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table.column('Report', width=120, minwidth=30)

        headings = ['#0', 'Name', 'Age', 'Mobile Number', 'Report']
        txt_headings = ['', 'Name', 'Age', 'Mobile Number', 'Report']
        for i in range(len(headings)):
            self.t_table.heading(headings[i], text=f'{txt_headings[i]}', anchor=W)

        for x in self.report:
            self.t_table.insert(parent='', index='end', values=x)
        self.t_table.pack(ipadx=72, ipady=30)


        # ====== LOWER FRAME =======
        self.btneditmat = Button(self.lowestframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='orange', fg='DeepSkyBlue4',
                              text='Edit', bd=3, padx=3, width=12, cursor='hand2')
        self.btneditmat.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E, padx=(12, 5), pady=(10, 0))

        self.btndeletemat = Button(self.lowestframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='firebrick4', fg='orange',
                                text='Delete', bd=3, padx=3, width=12, cursor='hand2')
        self.btndeletemat.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0), pady=(10, 0))


        # ====== ENTRY FRAME =======
        self.selectedmat = StringVar(value="Choose material:")
        self.matlbl = Label(self.entryframe, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange', text='Material',
                             padx=2)
        self.matlbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0))
        self.entrymat = ttk.Combobox(self.entryframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.selectedmat,
                                 width=18, state='readonly')
        self.entrymat['values'] = ["Bracket", "Toothbrush", "Toothpaste"]
        self.entrymat.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(3, 0), pady=5)

        self.selectedqty = StringVar()
        self.qtylbl = Label(self.entryframe, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='DeepSkyBlue4', fg='orange', text='Price',
                             padx=2)
        self.qtylbl.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0))
        self.entryqty = Entry(self.entryframe, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.selectedqty,
                                 bd=3,
                                 width=20, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.entryqty.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(3, 0), pady=5)

        self.btnaddmaterial = Button(self.entryframe, font=('arial', 11, 'bold'), bg='dark green', fg='orange',
                             text='Add', bd=3, padx=3, width=12, cursor='hand2')
        self.btnaddmaterial.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0))


        self.materiallist = [('Brackets', '2500.00')]
        # ===== BOTTOM FRAME =======
        # ====== Scrollbar =========
        self.t_scroll1 = Scrollbar(self.bottomframe)
        self.t_scroll1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # ======= Treeview table / BottomFrame ========
        self.t_table1 = ttk.Treeview(self.bottomframe, yscrollcommand=self.t_scroll1.set)
        self.tree_view_style1 = ttk.Style()
        self.tree_view_style1.theme_use('default')
        self.tree_view_style1.configure("Treeview", background='DeepSkyBlue4', foreground='black', fieldbackground='DeepSkyBlue4')
        self.tree_view_style1.map("Treeview", background=[('selected', 'orange')], foreground=[('selected', 'black')])
        self.tree_view_style1.configure("Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Arial', 10))


        self.t_scroll1.config(command=self.t_table1.yview)

        self.t_table1['column'] = ('Materials', 'Price')

        self.t_table1.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
        self.t_table1.column('Materials', width=80, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table1.column('Price', width=100, minwidth=30)

        headings1 = ['#0', 'Materials', 'Price']
        txt_headings1 = ['', 'Materials', 'Price']
        for i in range(len(headings1)):
            self.t_table1.heading(headings1[i], text=f'{txt_headings1[i]}', anchor=W)

        for x in self.materiallist:
            self.t_table1.insert(parent='', index='end', values=x)
        self.t_table1.pack(ipadx=56)        

    def view_patient(self):
        self.open_window3 = Toplevel(self.master1)
        self.app = Window2(self.open_window3)

class Window2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master3 = master
        width = 550
        height = 322
        screen_width = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = master.winfo_screenheight()

        x_coordinate = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
        y_coordinate = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
        self.master3.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
        self.master3.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master3.title('Wonder Smile Management System')

        self.topframe3 = Frame(self.master3, width=400, height=50, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, bd=3)
        self.topframe3.grid(row=0)

        self.rightframe3 = Frame(self.master3, width=367, height=680, bg='DeepSkyBlue4', relief=RIDGE, bd=3)
        self.rightframe3.grid(row=1)


        self.titlename3 = Label(self.topframe3, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), fg='orange', bg='DeepSkyBlue4', text='Patient List')
        self.titlename3.pack(padx=212)
        
        self.patientlist = [('Arsher', 20, 'Dasma', '12/25/00', '09512451255')]
        # ====== Scrollbar =========
        self.t_scroll3 = Scrollbar(self.rightframe3)
        self.t_scroll3.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # ======= Treeview table ========
        self.t_table3 = ttk.Treeview(self.rightframe3, yscrollcommand=self.t_scroll3.set)
        self.tree_view_style3 = ttk.Style()
        self.tree_view_style3.theme_use('default')
        self.tree_view_style3.configure("Treeview", background='DeepSkyBlue4', foreground='black', fieldbackground='DeepSkyBlue4')
        self.tree_view_style3.map("Treeview", background=[('selected', 'orange')], foreground=[('selected', 'black')])
        self.tree_view_style3.configure("Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Arial', 10))

        self.t_scroll3.config(command=self.t_table3.yview)

        self.t_table3['column'] = ('Name', 'Age', 'Address', 'Birthday', 'Mobile Number')

        self.t_table3.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
        self.t_table3.column('Name', width=75, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table3.column('Age', width=30)
        self.t_table3.column('Address', width=75, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table3.column('Birthday', width=50, minwidth=30)
        self.t_table3.column('Mobile Number', width=50, minwidth=30)

        headings = ['#0', 'Name', 'Age', 'Address', 'Birthday', 'Mobile Number']
        txt_headings = ['', 'Name', 'Age', 'Address', 'Birthday', 'Mobile Number']
        for i in range(len(headings)):
            self.t_table3.heading(headings[i], text=f'{txt_headings[i]}', anchor=W)

        for x in self.patientlist:
            self.t_table3.insert(parent='', index='end', values=x)
        self.t_table3.pack(ipadx=122, ipady=30,)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Comment: You've posted a huge amount of code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried simply removing parts of the code in `Window2` until the problem goes away? That would tell you what code is causing the problem.